# Rails how to connect database when I open the rails console?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, rails-activerecord

Once I open the rails console, I can retrieve data from the database(mysql...) using Active Record.

I know rails will read the `database.yml`. But when? and how to preserve database connections? when to release the database connections?

Comment: The Rails server reads the database.yml and the configuration files at startup. Usually you don't need to worry about preserving database connections - rails open a connection when needed and closes it when the request finishes. As long as your queries are not extremely long running you won't run out of connections.

Comment: @max If I exit from rails console, the database connection will release?

Comment: Yes. But why worry? It's not like you are going to run out of database connections in your development environment.

Comment: @Max I am just curious.